# Can I shave if my beard is uncomfortable?

Tags: halal-haram, beard

my Beard is very thick and coarse,and it is uncomfortable.

can I shave if it causes discomfort and slight pain?

Comment: What about trimming it short (a few mm long)?

Comment: There is a Hadith where the Prophet allowed one of his (male) sahabi to wear silk, even though its forbidden for men. Because the sahabi had a skin itch problem.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping a beard is prescribed in Islam as it has been commanded by the Prophet ﷺ <sup>[(Bukhari 5893](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5893))</sup>, and hence shaving it is haram according to the majority view <sup>([Mawsoo‘ah al-Fiqhiyyah 35/225](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/22529)) , ( [Fiqh al-Islami wa Adillatuhu 1/462](https://shamela.ws/book/384/444))</sup>. As such you should **not** shave your beard, even if you find it uncomfortable.

You could trim what is more than a fistful, as that is considered permissible by a group based on the practice of Ibn Umar <sup>([Bukhari 5892](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5892))</sup>. And you can use products which will soften the hair, such as oils and conditioners etc. A hydrated and clean beard should be softer. Also with time you might get used to it.

Comment: the malikis like shaykh al adawi allow it if you don't resemble a woman(wich I will admit,I am very feminine and neotenous without facial hair,and a beard does make me look masculine).the shafi'i later mujtahids say its makruh.

Answer (score -2):

No. You are not allowed to shave your beard based on below evidences.

> An-Nisaa’ (5232) reported from al-Baraa’ that he (peace and blessings
> of Allaah be upon him) had a **thick beard**; according to another
> report, he had a bushy beard; according to another report, he had a
> wide beard.
>
> Abu Hurayrah (رضي الله عنه) stated that Allah’s Messenger (صلى الله
> عليه وسلم) said: “Trim down the moustaches and grow the beards long
> and differ from the Magians (Fire Worshippers) Source: Muslim, 260
>
> Ibn ‘Abbās (رضي الله عنهما) who narrated: “Allah’s Messenger (صلى الله
> عليه وسلم) cursed the men who resemble women and he cursed the women
> who resemble men.” Source: Bukhāri, 5885
>
> There is a hadeeth collected by At-Tirmidhi (no. 2762) wherein it is
> said: “The Prophet would take from the width and length of his beard.”
> This hadeeth is fabricated (mawdoo’) as stated by the scholars of
> hadeeth, because there is a narrator in the chain called ‘Umar ibn
> Hāroon Al-Balkhi who was accused of lying. So, this hadeeth cannot be
> used as a proof for cutting the beard unrestrictedly from its length
> or its width. To act upon this fabricated narration opposes the
> authentic Sunnah. Furthermore, to act upon it knowingly just because
> it agrees with one’s desires is an added calamity that combines
> opposition to the Sunnah with following one’s inclination to imitate
> the unbelievers. Tirmidhi 2762; See Ad-Da’eefah of Al-Albāni, 288